# Multiple popup window layers position in CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css, popup

Hi I have a Jquery popup window that has three layers as the image below. I'm trying to make window3 to be centered so that it overlaps with window2. For some reason, window3 stays at the top-left corner as the image. I tried many different ways(padding, margin, z-index, position..) but no matter what I do, window3 won't be centered. Maybe I missed something and hope to get some other ideas. I didn't post the HTML since it contains those three windows div tags with bunch data-fields that are generated from a Javascript something like below.

[image]

```
function( contentUrl, container, tHeight, tWidth, controller, param ){              

            if( container === "dialog" ){
                var mask = '<div class="mask"></div>';
                var window3 = '<div class="window3"></div>';

                $(mask).appendTo('body');
                $(window3).appendTo('body');
```

style.css

```
 .mask {
        position: fixed;
        left: 0;
        top: 0;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        background: #000000;
        opacity: 0.7;
        z-index: 10;
    }          

 .window1 {
        background: #006666;
        width:430px;
        height:330px;
        opacity: 0.5;        
        padding:10px;
    }

 .window2 {
        background: #fff;              
        width:400px;
        height:300px;
        border-radius:14px;
        margin:10px; 
    }

.window3{   
        position: fixed;
        background: #ffffff;
        margin: auto;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        border-radius:14px;
        z-index: 10;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

Position: relative; on window 3